# Failing to start docker image in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am getting this error:

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
docker run -p 9988:1433 aneste:mssql
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\a\_temp\31deb425-e236-4cf3-bfe7-aed9ce46dd35.cmd""
.\start : The term '.\start' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... e = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; .\start -sa_pas ...
+                                                           ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\start:String) [], ParentConta 
   insErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

I have tried to search for a solution for a while now but can't seem to find one, not eaven sure what causes it, `docker ls` outputs the docker image correctly.

**EDIT:**
[Yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDX06.png)

Comment: I get the same error if I use "docker-compose up" too

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: We use Project/Project collection build service account in Azure DevOps pipeline. Do you have any specific permission requirement to run the steps in Docker image? Besides, are you able to succeed to  run the docker image locally?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Yes, when tested locally everything worked , no there's shouldn't be any specific permission requirements either...

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Sorry I can't really share much from that pipeline as there might be some sensitive data.

Comment: @Shuma Are you using Microsoft host agent or self-host agent? Instead of whole pipeline, could you share your docker related step setting/screenshot here.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I am using Microsoft host agent I will update question with screenshot of yaml file

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I am using this agent: pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

Comment: @Shuma Could it caused by some of your commands in your docker image such as bash is a prerequisite for Linux based containers. Give a try with Linux vmImage:'ubuntu-18.04'. Check if this do the trick.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Dont have bash anywhere, and made sure to use windows dialect everywhere, also Linux wont work for me because i need .NET framework to run aswell on the same pipeline.